# Specify jQuery for bootstrap in webpack

Tags: webpack

In my project, I want to import Bootstrap, but it depends on jQuery.

```
require('jquery/dist/jquery.min'); 
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min');
```

When I use Webpack to handle this project, it causes an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

How can I specify jQuery for Bootstrap?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Replace your `require` statement with the following:

`window.jQuery = window.$ =  require('jquery/dist/jquery.min');`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I've got an error `window is not defined`. What I did wrong?

Comment: please add , interface Window { jQuery: any; $: any; } in any.d.ts file

Comment: another option is [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader)

Answer (score 5):

```
require('!!script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
```

The `!!script!` is a special flag that will inline the script without using any loaders, equivalent to using a `<script>` tag in HTML.