# 'jquery is not defined' when using webpack to load bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am just starting to learn to use Webpack (previously I just use the manual way to include individual scripts separately). And I used `bootstrap-loader` for loading bootstrap. Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path")
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,

    entry: './assets/js/index', // entry point of our app. assets/js/index.js should require other js modules and dependencies it needs

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
    },

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}, // to transform JSX into JS
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}, // to transform css
            // images
            { test: /\.png$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'},
            { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            // bootstrap image files
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ],
    },

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        jquery: './vendor/jquery/jquery.js',
    },
}
```

And here is my entry.js

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-loader');
```

This seems to work. However, I used this before and it did not work:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

I found the line above suggested by so many people. But I just simply get errors when load the page. Just some examples: [some SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382444/specify-jquery-for-bootstrap-in-webpack), [webpack issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/108), [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969861/managing-jquery-plugin-dependency-in-webpack).

Later I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651015/webpack-using-bootstrap-jquery-is-not-defined), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651015/webpack-using-bootstrap-jquery-is-not-defined). So the page actually works with bootstrap js functionality working as well.

I will add my package.json as well in case it is relevant:

```
{
  "author": "franklingu",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^1.2.0-beta.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

I am new to webpack but I am not new to JS. I am wondering why `window.$` is not working.

And I wonder, for webpack, why some people suggested this in plugins:

```
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
        })
```

Some people are suggesting this (did not work for me either):

```
 resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    }
}
```

I played with node for a while back then and I remembered that node makes use of request js for loading(I am not very clear about differences between common vs require vs amd though). But why some people mention common js?

I was developing backend for some time and just started frontend--so many questions are popping up. It would just enough if you provide me with some link to some guide to read which can clear my doubts/build my basic understanding of these.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Add this as plugin

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: "jquery",
   jQuery: "jquery"
  })
```

and you should be able to have jquery in your whole project.

If issue persists after adding the plugin, try restarting your `nodejs` server. Remember to install `jquery` using `npm install --save jquery`.

Comment: I did put this in my question. maybe you can just read it again. Did not work for me this solution

Comment: if you using this plugin it should work and you don't need to set alias.. [check this seed](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/es6-webpack-bootstrap-material-design)

Comment: Note: once you have pluged jquery with webpack plugin you don't need to import it with require and you can go to dev tools and type $ to see that jquery has loaded. i don't see anything else strange in you code it should just work :-)

Comment: chrome actually ships with its own $--according to what I know. But I will go back and try it again. Just this solution

Comment: weird. I definitely have tried this approach before and it did not work for me. but now it seems to be fine

Comment: @JunchaoGu Had the same issue, restarting `node` server did the trick.

Comment: This is not working for me with Webpack 4.8.3.   Did a process recently change? I have the plugin set in place.  I also have jquery 3.3.1 installed via npm.  I can run npm start, but the browser does not load jquery.

Comment: never-mind, I had to restart my entire environment.  thanks for posting this answer!

Comment: Are there any other steps required other than using code above and `npm install jquery`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was on the verge of beating my head against the wall.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a bit old, but I managed to do it like that :

global.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

Answer (score 12):

Plugin is not needed. Just use following as entry:

```
entry: [
    'jquery', //will load jquery from node_modules
    './assets/js/index',
]
```

Then in ES6+ file use:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

Comment: Does this work in Webpack 2? Does this make sure that `index` will not be executed until `jquery` has been executed?

Comment: @Flimm Webpack 2 has no change on the 'entry' part, so should work there as well.

Comment: @Flimm Good one, put 'jquery' as first record :). I updated my answer.

Comment: When using single entry file with jQuery import, I get jQuery is not defined in chrome dev tools for this file (imported after jquery) :  https://css-tricks.com/examples/Loadingdotdotdot/js/jquery.loadingdotdotdot.js

Comment: @user1063287 the import is local scope. When import statement is not in your mentioned file, it will not be available. Hack is maybe to import in the entry file and set global: window.jQuery = $. I have not enough background info to give a better suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

I want to share my findings for any future developer who might have the same use-case I do.

I had the requirement to only create a vendor bundle and not an app bundle for an **AngularJS** (1.7.2) app, using **Webpack 4** (4.16.4).  I think because I was only creating a vendor bundle, none of the other solutions worked.  Only `expose-loader` worked for me, like so:

```
    // webpack.config.js
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                use: [{
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: 'jQuery'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: '$'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

For more information:  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader

Comment: Just add that is needed to add "expose-loader" dependency to the project

Comment: Also note, that you need to install `expose-loader: ^1.0.0` other wise you will get: `TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function`, because `expose-loader ^2.0.0`  requires webpack 5